# how to add accessoryType to subview of tableviewcell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I would like to know how to set an accessory type, like a disclosure to the subview of a UITableViewCell?

I know how to do this with a activity indicator, but not sure how to do it with a disclosure button?... anyhelp would be great.

This is how I do the activity indicator at the moment.. then when i want to use it I just call start or stop animating.

```
cellActivityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        // Position the spinner
        [cellActivityIndicator setCenter:CGPointMake(280.0, 24.0)];

        // Add to button
        [cell addSubview:cellActivityIndicator];
```

This is what is happening when the disclosure indicator appears on the right of the uitableviewcell, it is pushing the label out to the left... (label currently has "empty" in it)

[image]

This is what happens when I have auto resizing and try to use swipe to delete

[image]

Comment: **[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton];**

Comment: sorry I should have said I know how to add a dsclosure button.. but I would like to add it to a subview of the tableviewcell because at the moment its totaly messing with my right aligned labels positioning...

Comment: You have to aligned your label properly in your tableviewcell's initWithStyle based on disclosurebutton.

Comment: how do I do that. I have just been placing it in interface builder, it needs to be right aligned so that when i use swipe to delete the label moves to the left as the delete button appears.

Comment: did you try that code which i mentioned in comment before ?

Comment: yes, It is still pushing my label out to the right.. I will show you a screen shot of what is happening.

Comment: I do not know but i still remember that i had the same issue in my previous app and i solved it by set the alignment of label either in initWithStyle or drawRect method in UITableViewCell's subclass.

Comment: okay thank you for the help, I will try and look into solving it with the suggestion you just made.

Answer (score 0):

You are going about this wrong, you should add your custom subviews like this:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:cellActivityIndicator];
```

The cell content view is resized to take into account accessory views, so any subviews that you have added will be shifted into the correct place (assuming you have sized them correctly and have the right `autoresizingMask` flags).

Comment: so do I change the autoresizing mask of the label or the indicators/disclosurebutton?
And also do you have a little more information about why I'm going about this wrong.. as I am keen to get this right..

Comment: if you are doing it in IB, you can set the label to be resize with the cell like you would any view, by activating the right and left peg in the Autosizing box. if you are doing it in code, set the autoresizing mask of the label to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`.

Comment: ah so i think I have done autoresizing in Interface builder (please check the new image I have added to my question) however I have one issue with it, if someone selects swipe to delete then the swipe to delete button appears over the uilabel.. so am I doing something wrong or is this the usual behaviou?